# How to check a value is already in a grid?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using the following to add  values from a `combobox` and `textbox` into a  `grid`.

```
Dim pdt, pdtid As String
Dim i As Integer
pdt = cboProducts.Columns(0).Text
pdtid = cboProducts.Columns(1).Text.ToString
If grdSale.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    i = 0
Else
    i = i + grdSale.Rows.Count
End If
grdSale.AddRows(1)
grdSale(i, 1) = pdt
grdSale(i, 0) = pdtid
grdSale(i, 3) = txtQty.Text
grdSale.Splits(0).DisplayColumns(0).Visible = False
```

So how can I check duplicates in `grid`, i.e if I enter a `product` that is already in the grid then I need to show a warning message?

Comment: What have you tried? Try asking yourself questions and then perform them in code. Questions like: What do I need to check if a value is in the list? Ans: All rows and a Value. Can I fetch all rows? <yes/no> Can I fetch the value to compare from this row? <yes/no> Do I know how to compare two strings? <yes/no>. Start with this and see what you come up with.

Comment: you know a) what column the prodID is in b) the text of the new prodID to be added and c) how many rows the DGV has. so just look thru the DGV rows to see if that prodID exists before adding.

Comment: A grid is the UI part that displays data from a datatable/datasource. Any changes should be made to the datasource and displayed using the grid. Add a row to the datasource checking for duplicates there and then refresh your grid.

Comment: Agree with @Gary. Always do validations against a business object, rather than the UI elements which represents your data. Your code will look nicer, work faster etc.

Comment: Okay I finally worked it. I used to iterate through the grid and checked the prodid in combobox(when selects the item to pass to grid) with each rows in the grid's prodId column ..       **Thanks for your support**